# Is there a way to average data that has a common value in a column?

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc, analysis

I have some CSV files that I have to format, which is the easy part, but then I have to create an average for values in each column based on the hour. The hour is in its own column and the values are all in columns as well. Is it possible to have OpenOffice Calc average the data of all the data that has a value that are equal? My data looks like this:
[image: Ouput in Openoffice after edits]
This would really help with my time since I have a new set of data everyday and I do these once every other week.

Comment: What is actually in the date,  Hr, and Min columns and how does it get there?  For example, are they actual values contained in the CSV, or something converted to that form and perhaps formatted in Excel?  Are the hours 0-23?  What form should the results take and where should they appear (separate output table, next to appropriate rows on the existing table, etc.)?  Are you looking for an average for each column D:L?

Comment: The date hour and min columns are imported as is, while the rest of the columns I edit once imported. Hours is based on 24hour time, military time. Right now I am using a series of averageif statements connected to each column.```=AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$1440;"0"($G$2:$G$1440))``` and I change the "0" to equal the hour I need averaged and the G will get change when i need a new column.

Comment: Take a look at pivot tables.  They're a simple way to aggregate data like this, and averaging is a built-in function.  Date and hour would be rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being my best answer for simplicity reasons:
The date hour and min columns are imported as is, while the rest of the columns I edit once imported. Hours is based on 24hour time, military time. Right now I am using a series of averageif statements connected to each column.=AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$1440;"0"($G$2:$G$1440)) and I change the "0" to equal the hour I need averaged and the G will get change when i need a new column.